# Ignore an empty text field

Tags: vba

[image]

I keep getting a cast exception when running a subroutine in a userform.
It recognizes the null value when it reads `txtMileage.text = ""` and throws an error because it's trying to determine if the value is greater than 300

`If btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text > 300 Then
            MsgBox("Distance Exceeds 300 Miles")
            txtMileage.Focus()
            Exit Sub`

I need it to ignore checking the value when `btnNo.checked = true` and `txtMileage.text = ""`

Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCalculate.Click
    If btnNo.Checked = False And btnYes.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("Please select yes or no")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please instert Mileage")
        txtMileage.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If btnNo.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text = "" Then

    End If
    If btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text > 300 Then
        MsgBox("Distance Exceeds 300 Miles")
        txtMileage.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

updated with error message, it still throws it at

`If btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please insert Mileage")
            txtMileage.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text > 300 Then
            MsgBox("Distance Exceeds 300 Miles")
            txtMileage.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If`

`ElseIf btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text > 300 Then` seems to be the problem line at the last `Then`

Comment: I dont know anything about vba, can you use regex to check for fields?

Comment: It shouldn't even get to the ElseIf when `.Text = ""` so that means that `.Text <> ""`. Try putting in the following line before the `If` statement to see what the value of `.Text` is: `Debug.Print "~" & txtMileage.Text & "~"` (If the Immediate window isn't on, you could use `Msgbox` instead of `Debug.Print`)

Comment: it may be that I need to convert the strings to integers...

Comment: Message=Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.
I'm not sure exactly what this error message means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just checking if `.Text` contains a numeric value and, if it doesn't, setting it to be `0`?

```
If Not IsNumeric(txtMileage.Text) Then txtMileage.Text = 0
```

You may or may not want to store it as a variable instead to avoid changing the control.

```
Dim txt as Variant
txt = txtMileage.Text
If Not IsNumeric(txt) Then txt  = 0
```

Comment: A little adaptation to my code and this method works.

Answer (score 1):

Put it as excluyent option through `elseif` of  `txtMileage.Text = ""`. There won't be a chance that it does the check `if >300` when is empty.

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCalculate.Click
    If btnNo.Checked = False And btnYes.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("Please select yes or no")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please instert Mileage")
        txtMileage.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Elseif  btnYes.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text > 300 Then
        MsgBox("Distance Exceeds 300 Miles")
        txtMileage.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If btnNo.Checked = True And txtMileage.Text = "" Then

    End If
End Sub
```